# Programatic launching of application on windows startup

Tags: windows, startup, launch

I have a particular piece of software that i wish to load on windows startup. Under normal circumstances i would simply place a shortcut in the startup folder or an entry in the run key in the registry.

Unfortunately and for an unknown reason this application throws a win32 execption whenever that is done - and i am assuming it is because an element of windows has not been loaded that is vital to this application.

Once windows has actually loaded i can double click on the icon and it runs fine. So my question is - is there a programmatic solution to this? I have already tried a console app launcher that sleeps for n seconds and then launches but all that seems to do is delay the startup of windows.

Does anyone have any creative solutions? I am open to anything from a windows service to c#, vb, batch files.. etc

Thx

Comment: Why don't you log the exception to fix the actual error that is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run it as a service, or write a shell service which will attempt to start it up?  That way you will have built in support for response on failure and delay time before trying again.

Comment: I could but how would i know when to get it to fire... i almost need to listen to a windows event that says "Im ready now!"

Comment: @Grant That's what I'm saying - the service will fire it off, it'll fail, the service management stuff will say 'the service failed, we'll try starting it again in 1 minute', repeat up to three times.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at AUTOEXEC.BAT. But be careful!!